# How to find a function by function name

Tags: javascript

I need to find a function handler on the page by only using a function name.
How can I do it in javascript?

Comment: I literally have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: In this case this really is a case of LMGTFY: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+function+name+string

Comment: So you have some javascript functions defined within the page, and are trying to find which ones are available, from within another of the functions on the page?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+function+name+string

Answer (score 3):

If you have the function name, just call it?

e.g. if you want to call a function called "foo" then just call:

```
foo();
```

if you have the name in a variable, then call:

```
window[funcName]();
```